# Awstat Warning: Tried to load plugin "geoip" twice. Fix config file

Tags: ubuntu, webmin, awstats

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with the web-based system configuration webmin.

So awstat is install by default.

I installed manually the plug-ins geoip and GeopIPCity plug-in but it's not working and I get this warning message: `Tried to load plugin "geoip" twice. Fix config file.` and `Tried to load plugin "geoip_city_maxmind" twice. Fix config file.`

There are these two lines on `/etc/awstats/awstats.conf`

```
LoadPlugin="geoip GEOIP_STANDARD /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat"
LoadPlugin="geoip_city_maxmind GEOIP_STANDARD /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat"
```

But also in the awstat conf files of virtual hosts.

The .dat files are in the good location:

```
root@Ubuntu-14LTS-NY1:/etc/awstats# ll /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 827301 Apr  7  2014 /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat

root@Ubuntu-14LTS-NY1:/etc/awstats# ll /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19756029 Apr 16 04:18 /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
```

I don't where to check to fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice, why twice !

So I took a look at the config files. And there is a main config file and virtual hosts config files.

```
    root@Ubuntu-14LTS-NY1:~# ll /etc/awstats/awstats.*
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62092 Apr  1 05:14 /etc/awstats/awstats.mywebsite1.org.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62057 Apr 21 17:59 /etc/awstats/awstats.conf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   240 Nov 16  2013 /etc/awstats/awstats.conf.local
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 61915 Apr 21 17:14 /etc/awstats/awstats.mywebsite2.net.conf
```

So if I modify `/etc/awstats/awstats.conf` to add the line L`oadPlugin="geoip GEOIP_STANDARD /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat"` I must not add it to the website config file `/etc/awstats/awstats.mywebsite1.org.conf` for example.

I thought it strange reaction of config files. Loading twice !